# Avoid overwriting of Image file and Create a new One

Tags: c#, winforms, aforge

I'm using AForge framework to capture an image to webcam, after capturing the image. The user will confirm if he/she want it as his image. If yes the image will be save on my project directory.

Here's the problem when i save the image it overrides the first one

What i want is to create a new file when new image is created but i don't know how i gonna do that.

For Example:
The first image will be saved as Image01, then the new will be Image02 and so on..

Here's my code

```
 ImageHelper img = new ImageHelper();

    private void ImageCapture_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        img.ImageSettings
        (
            img._captureDevice,
            img.finalFrame,
            cboxWebcamType
        );

        img.finalFrame.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);

        btnOk.Hide();
        btnCancel.Hide();
    }

    private void FinalFrame_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        picPreviewImage.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }
    private void ImageCapture_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (img.finalFrame.IsRunning == true)
            img.finalFrame.Stop();
    }
    private void BtnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        picCapturedImage.Image = (Bitmap)picPreviewImage.Image.Clone();
        picCapturedImage.BringToFront();

        btnCapture.Hide();
        btnOk.Show();
        btnCancel.Show();
    }
    private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (picCapturedImage.Image != null)
        {
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(picCapturedImage.Image);
            var newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap);
            bitmap.Save(@"..\..\Resources\Image01.Png", ImageFormat.Png);

            bitmap.Dispose();
            bitmap = null;
        }


        Close();
    }
    private void BtnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of using a single fixed string literal for the file path in your code, use `string.format` or simple string concatenation (like `string myString = "Dang" + someNumberVariable`) to build your file name dynamically according to your needs  (side note: you might also want to look into using `System.IO.Path.Combine` when dynamically building a path from a file name and directory components). Plenty of C# tutorials covering strings can teach you all the nitty-gritty details of string creation/composition...

Comment: can you elaborate it ?  i know string concatenation . but still doesn't get what your trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something simple and don't want to hold a state of how many pictures you have, you can loop through file names until you find a unique one.

```
private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (picCapturedImage.Image != null)
    {
        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(picCapturedImage.Image))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                var fileName = @$"..\..\Resources\Image{i}.png";

                if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    bitmap.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Close();
}
```

Comment: I thought that too, but don't know how to construct it. Great Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can change your method to something like this

```
private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (picCapturedImage.Image != null)
        {
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(picCapturedImage.Image);
            var newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap);
            string imageName=@"..\..\Resources\"+ "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss-fff")+".Png"
            bitmap.Save(imageName, ImageFormat.Png);

            bitmap.Dispose();
            bitmap = null;
        }


        Close();
    }
```

this way the current date and time added to image name and you can always be sure it's unique,but of course there are a lot of other ways to do this. hope it helps

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Thank you